# Mostrar anuncio intersticial y después Activity al presionar un botón

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, admob

El problema que tengo es que al presionar un botón se muestra, activity y luego el intersticial, y me gustaría que sea, intersticial y luego activity, con esto me refiero a que primero aparece el activity por un par de segundos al presionar el botón y me gustaría que primero apareciera el intersticial

```
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");

            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: en el onclick() solo cargas el anuncio, donde cargas la Activity y como lo realizas?

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.imageButton2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main8Activity.this,Main10Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });` soy nuevo en esto de programar disculpa

Comment: Haz uso de un Handler, revisa la respuesta.

Comment: Hola veo que quitaste mi respuesta como solución entonces no te sirvió?

Comment: todo bien en el intersticial de prueba pero al poner el verdadero se cerraba toda la app luego de los 3 segundos

Comment: Pero que error se mostraba en el LogCat,es importante comentarlo en la pregunta.

Comment: ya lo solucione con onAdClosed() pero me encontré con otro ploblema  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394841/como-abrir-intersticial-cada-vez-que-presiono-un-boton

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes realizar es hacer uso de un `Handler` para esperar algunos segundos después de la carga del anuncio y mostrar la `Activity`:

```
findViewById(R.id.imageButton2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            //Muestra anuncio.
            mInterstitialAd.show();

            //Despues de mostrar el anuncio Insterticial, realiza el intent.
            Handler myHandler = new Handler();
            myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Main8Activity.this, Main10Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }, 3000); //3 segundos
            
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
        }
       
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

por si alguien tiene algún problema similar, la solución que me dio Elenasys me sirvió para el intersticial de prueba pero cuando puse el codigo de publicidad de verdad (la publicidad en general "la real" donde aparecen diferentes clases de publicidad, espero me entiendan) luego de 3 segundos se cierra toda la app así que investigue y encontré esta solución

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();

                    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
          //esto fue lo que me funciono, básicamente hace que luego de cerrar la publicidad
          se realice lo que desees
                        @Override
                        public void onAdClosed() {
                          //en aqui dentro pones lo que desees hacer, el intent por ejemplo
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
                }
```

aun no lo probé ya que si fallo al presionar el X de la publicidad y le doy en el anuncio google admob me podría bloquear la cuenta asi que si esta mal esta respuesta la editare