# como abrir intersticial cada vez que presiono un boton

Tags: android-studio, botón, admob

en mi reciclerview donde tengo botones luego de presionar el boton me sale el intersticial pero luego de presionarlo otra vez ya no sale el anuncio y va directamente a la acción determinada que le di al boton como podría solucionar esto?

```
        MobileAds.initialize(holder.itemView.getContext(),
                "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(holder.itemView.getContext());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                //aquí va el intent me parece innecesario 
            }
        });

        holder.boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();

                } else {
                    //en aqui creo que es el problema, no se que poner exactamente, probe poniendo 
                      algunas cosas para ver si funcionaba pero tenia otros resultados un poco diferentes 
                      a lo que quería lograr
                }


            }

        });
```

Comment: intente poniendo desde MobileAds hasta onAdClosed pero luego de presionar el boton la primera vez tengo que presionar 2 veces para que funcione talvez exista otra forma

Comment: Prueba a cargar un nuevo anuncio en onAdClosed. Así, cuando cierras el anuncio actual tendrás otro preparado para la próxima interacción. Si no lo haces, no tendrás ningún anuncio precargado y es cuando tú código pasa por el else de tu onClick

Comment: funciona las 2 primeras veces pero luego ya no responde, aclaro que borre el contenido del else

Comment: @JPery dentro de onAdClosed puse el anuncio incluyendo otro onAdClosed dentro y en el if hice lo mismo y me esta funcionando, es posible que sea demasiado código y exista otra forma?